# Show array address in C++ (Code Blocks)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new at C++ and I'd like to show an array's address using the Code::Blocks feature `Watches`

The line code I want to check is this `char hello[7] = "hello";`

When I launch `Debug` and I open the `Watches` window, it only shows `"hello\000\000"`.

If I try somthing else like `char *hi = "hi";`, the `Watches` window shows

`0x46e024 <_ZSt16__convert_from_vRKPiPciPKcz+4644900> "hi"` so as you see, it shows the address as well as the value.

How can I do the same with `hello` ? I mean showing its address?

Thanks!

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek I tried it but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that the debugger is too intelligent and automatically interprets the address.
The address is already the value of `hello`. There is no need to take the address of that variable with `&` as the other answers suggest.

Would you could probably do is use another variable that is explictly a pointer, assign hello to that and look up that value in the debugger:

```
char hello[7] = "hello";
char* helloaddr = hello;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use that:

```
char* array = 'trololo';
int addr = &array;
```

Comment: I tried that but it shows an error in the second line!

Comment: To be precise, there are 2 errors on the first line already (in addition to that on the second): 1) Multi-character character literal, 2) assigned to a pointer to non-const.